# strings and isdigit function

Tags: c, string, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int digit(s1);
int main()
{char s1[10];
printf("\n Type anything you want:\n");
gets(s1);
printf("The number of digits is:%d",digit(s1));
return 0;
}
int digit(char* s1)
{
    int i=0;
  while(*s1)
{
i+= !!isdigit(*s1++);
}
return i;
}
```

This is my code, I need to find out is the element that I give a digit or not.
I change it into void digit and it runs perfectly now.

Comment: Please take notice of compiler warnings - you pass the wrong type to `isdigit` --- OH you `#include <ctype.h>` but rewrite the library function `isdigit` quite differently. The code doesn't even compile, for other reasons too.

Comment: Your function needs to return a value indicating its result, which then needs to be used by the code in `main`. Also, please do not use `gets` function. It is no longer part of the c library.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats what I learn from lecture notes, what should I write for second return? I know that I need to write something at the very bottom but don't know what exactly

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit` is a standard C function declared in `<ctype.h>`. Your function conflicts with it. Choose a different name for your function.

That will avoid the compiler message about conflicting types, but there are other errors in your program you will need to fix.

Comment: I choose a different name for it but couldn't understand the rest. I should write something at the bottom like second return but don't know what to write exactly

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has several major issues. If the lecture says to use `gets()`, throw it into the trash, use `fgets()` instead. The reason why, you can find in this link:

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Apart from that, The lecture seems to not even provided you the knowledge to correctly pass parameters or to output values of variables correctly.

I recommend you to read a good C starting book, f.e. [this](https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf). A list of recommended books can be also found here:

[The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

To only focus one issue, the output:

```
printf("There are %d digits in your string.");
```

This use of `printf()` is incorrect. Where shall the value specified by `%d` come from? The `%d` format specifier is missing a corresponding argument which points to an integer value or an `int` variable, like:

```
int a = 10;
printf("a = %d",a);
```

`%d` requires a matching argument of type `int` to actually print a value. Else the [behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

This shall in all cases give a diagnostic. Never ignore compiler warnings.

---

[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: Our lecture notes has gets function thats why I used it, and I change it into `printf("The number of digits is:%d"); do you think is it okay now? but still I'm getting random numbers as a result 
`

Comment: @mesad No, the use of `printf()` is still completely wrong.

Comment: @mesad `%d` requires a matching argument of type `int` to actually print a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int count_digits(const char *s1);

int main()
{
    char s1[20];
    printf("\n Type anything you want:\n");
    fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);
    printf("The number of digits is:%d", count_digits(s1));
    return 0;
}

int count_digits(const char* s1)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(*s1) 
    {
        count += !!isdigit(*s1++);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note, that OP isn´t even be able to understand how to use a format specifier and passing function parameters. The code in `count_digits` will probably knock him out.

Comment: I'm still learning so could please explain the part "count += !!isdigit(*s1++);" I would be so greatful.What is that stands for?

Comment: @RobertS:  That is by design.   I gave him correct code that he can step through and study, but cannot turn in for his homework assignment.